# Passing first_name, last_name to User.objects.create_user() Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to register users using their first name, last name, username, email and password. I see in the [create_user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) in Django docs that first_name and last_name are included in the default fields of user model. However when I try to submit my register form, I get an error saying ***"create_user() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 6 were given"***. What is wrong with my code?

Anyway this can be fixed without creating custom user model? 
How can I pass the first_name and last_name to create_user() ?

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        qs = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Username is taken")
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("email is taken")
        return email

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password2 != password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match.")
        return data
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, get_user_model
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import LoginForm, RegisterForm

User = get_user_model()

def register_page(request):
    register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "register_form": register_form
    }

    if register_form.is_valid():
        username = register_form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        first_name = register_form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        last_name = register_form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
        email = register_form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = register_form.cleaned_data.get("password")

        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password, first_name, last_name)

    return render(request, "auth/register.html", context)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass them in as keyword arguments so that it has a name for the field to go with the value.

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user(
    username, email, password, 
    first_name=first_name,
    last_name=last_name,
)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! how come username, email and password don't need a name?

Comment: As Abdullah alluded to, they are positional arguments as seen in the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user Here's a blog post that should explain the difference between args and kwargs: https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Answer (score 1):

```
create_user(username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields)
```

The `**extra_fields` ar keyword argument means you should pass them as `first_name=first_name`

Read this, it may help:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User